# Installation issue "ext4fuse:Linux is required for this software." on Mac OS Mojave

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew

When I ran

> brew install ext4fuse

in Terminal (10.14.6), it returned

> ext4fuse: Linux is required for this software.
>
> libfuse@2: Linux is required for this software.
>
> Error: ext4fuse: Unsatisfied requirements failed this build.

How to resolve it?

Answer (score 15):

You might need to build it manually on your Mac.

Taken from https://github.com/gerard/ext4fuse/issues/74#issuecomment-1374069541:

- install mac4fuse from https://osxfuse.github.io/, restart
- Run the following in Terminal

```
git clone https://github.com/gerard/ext4fuse.git && cd "$(basename "$_" .git)"
make
mkdir ~/ext4_mount
diskutil list # shows you a list of all disks connected to your system, choose your ext4 disk/partition, let's assume it's /dev/disk4
sudo ./ext4fuse /dev/disk4 ~/ext4_mount -o allow_other # sudo is required
# approve all the security prompts, reboot
sudo ./ext4fuse /dev/disk4 ~/ext4_mount -o allow_other # run again after reboot
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I am unable to mount the image file before "sudo ./ext4fuse /dev/disk4 ~/ext4_mount -o allow_other".  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/454880/hdiutil-attach-unable-to-attach-image-file-on-mac-mojave. I will proceed to your method later.

Comment: also not working for me... :(

Comment: (macOS 14.3.1)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [ext4fuse] Error 1

Answer (score 0):

Using ext4fuse seems to result in Input/Output errors currently.

I had success mounting an ext4 partition as read/write with https://github.com/alperakcan/fuse-ext2#macos.