# .hdiutil attach unable to attach image file on Mac Mojave

Tags: macos, terminal, mount

I tried to attach image file (.img) as a disk in Terminal on Mojave (10.14.6) by

"hdiutil attach -imagekey diskimage-class=CRawDiskImage filename.img";

"hdiutil attach filename.img -ignorebadchecksums";

"hdiutil attach filename.img -noautofsck".

All of the above commands returned
"hdiutil: attach failed - no mountable file systems."

Please kindly note that I added checksums on the image file (.img) in Disk Utility before running the above commands.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Where is `filename.img` coming from and what kind of filesystem should be on it? Also, what do you mean with " I added checksums on the image file (.img) in Disk Utility", did you change the file or just verify the checksums?

Comment: filename.img is RAW image (shown as ndif image on Mac OS). "I added checksum" means that I opened Disk Utility, ran "Add checksum..." under "Images". No changes for the file.

Comment: Where does the IMG come from? Without any information of the filesystem which should be used on it, it will be nearly impossible to mount it.

Comment: The image format is NDIF.

Comment: wenyuan: Have you tried adding the `-mount suppressed` option to the `attach` verb?

Comment: -mount suppressed did not resolve the issue, the disk remained unattached.

Comment: The source of image file is irrelevant - whether it was ubuntu system image or external hard drive, hdiutil attach produced the same error message: "hdiutil: attach failed - no mountable file systems".

Comment: We ask clarification questions for a reason. If you don‘t want to answer them, it might become difficult to help you here.

Comment: Anyway: are we talking about https://fileinfo.com/extension/ndif? Can you change the extension from img to ndif and then try to open it in Disk Utility.app ?